# How can I fetch specific record from json file in android?

Tags: android, json

I have a text file in my SD card which contains json array. Say for example file is like this:

```
[
{"CountryID" : "1","CountryName" : "Australia"},
{"CountryID" : "2","CountryName" : "Japan"},
{"CountryID" : "3","CountryName" : "China"},
{"CountryID" : "4","CountryName" : "India"},
{"CountryID" : "5","CountryName" : "Holland"}
]
```

Now I want to fetch data based on Country ID. Ex. I want to pass ID = 2 and I get only one object. I can fetch whole file in a string variable and loop through each object to find my data. But I dont think it is best practice to do. Because in my real file I might have more than 1000 objects which I dont want to loop through.

Thanks

Comment: If this is your requirement then why you are not making a separate request for search based on country id?

Comment: @Dharmendra Thanks for your comment Dharmendra. Can you please elaborate your suggestion.

Comment: From where you are getting this json response?

Comment: I have pre-populated json file. Which I have put in to the SDCard.

Comment: @hirensoni were you able to read the file content from sd card ? the problem is only with the JSON parsing ?

Comment: @sunil Yes I have no problem in reading the file. I dont even say that I can't pars JSON data. Right now I am fetching whole file in to memory and then looping thru the file to find the object. I want to avoid that. I want that I fetch only one object which I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If there is going to be 1000 records then use sqllite instead. Json is not meant to be database structure.

Comment: I agree with you Prakash. But this is requirement i can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code sample to do your task

```
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Country>>() {}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = "["
            + "{\"CountryID\" : \"3\",\"CountryName\" : \"China\"},"
            + "{\"CountryID\" : \"2\",\"CountryName\" : \"Japan\"},"
            + "{\"CountryID\" : \"1\",\"CountryName\" : \"Australia\"},"
            + "{\"CountryID\" : \"4\",\"CountryName\" : \"India\"},"
            + "{\"CountryID\" : \"5\",\"CountryName\" : \"Holland\"}" 
            + "]";
    // parsing the JSON array
    ArrayList<Country> countries = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
    System.out.println(countries);

    // sorting the country list based on CountryID. Ensure list is sorted, since we do binary search next
    Collections.sort(countries);
    System.out.println(countries);

    Country searchKey = new Country(3,"");
    // searching for country with ID 3
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(countries, searchKey);
    if(index < 0 || index >= countries.size() ) System.out.println("Country with ID "+searchKey.getCountryID()+ " not found in results");
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Found Country with ID : " + searchKey.getCountryID()+ " @ index : " + index);
        Country searchResult = countries.get(index);
        System.out.println("Searched result : "+searchResult);
    }
```

- here i am using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse the `Country` list
- For this, i am using a data holder class named `Country`

find the class `Country`

```
public class Country implements Comparable<Country> {


    public Country(int countryID, String countryName) {
        super();
        CountryID = countryID;
        CountryName = countryName;
    }
    //"CountryID" : "1","CountryName" : "Australia"

    private int CountryID;
    private String CountryName;
    /**
     * Gets the countryID.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the countryID.</tt>
     */
    public int getCountryID() {
        return CountryID;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the countryID.
     *
     * @param countryID <tt> the countryID to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setCountryID(int countryID) {
        CountryID = countryID;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the countryName.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the countryName.</tt>
     */
    public String getCountryName() {
        return CountryName;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the countryName.
     *
     * @param countryName <tt> the countryName to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        CountryName = countryName;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country [CountryID=" + CountryID + ", CountryName="
                + CountryName + "]";
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Country o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.getCountryID()-o.getCountryID();
    }


}
```

- `Country` class implements `Comparable` interface to do the `Collections`' binary search
- After successful parsing, i sorted the `Country` list
- Then used the `binarySearch` of `Collections` class to find the index of your `search-key-country`
- Now just used the returned `index` to retrieve your `search-result-country` object